# JWT Bearer Keeps returning 401 Status = Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

Hello everyone it is been 6 hours I am struggling to solve this issue.

**I have the following projects:**

- Client App: ReactJS using axios library
- Server App: .NET Core Web api implementing JWT for authorization and authentication.

**The Problem:**

- when trying to send get request from my react application using axios to the backend and attaching the jwt in the header I always get 401 unauthorized.
- I tried the same way using postman It works perfectly !!!!!!!!!!

**My attempts:**

- I tried to add the cors to my api and allows every origin, every header, every method still did not work.

**Sending Request From ReactJS using axios:**

```
async function getAllUserTasks() {
    try {
      return axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "http://localhost:5133/todo/ToDos",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("jwtToken")}`,
        },
        body: {
          userId: JSON.stringify('924BF80F-F394-4927-8DCC-A7B67AFA663C')
        },
        

      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  //call the function one time
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllUserTasks();
  }, []);
```

**My config for the JWT in .NET app:**

```
services.AddAuthentication(defaultScheme: JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options => options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer,
                        ValidAudience = jwtSettings.Audience,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Secret))

                    });
```

**My config for policy and cors:**

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3000/")
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader();
                }));
```

This is really frustrating!

Comment: You are trying to send `body` with a get request, are you sure about that?

Comment: Apart from sending a body in a GET request (which no browser will do), is `localStorage.getItem("jwtToken")` resulting in a valid JWT? since there's no code that stores the JWT in localStorage, perhaps there is no JWT in localStorage?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I no it is kinda weird, but it worked with postman !

Comment: @JaromandaX in my login component I stored the jwt after the authorization process and I checked the value is valid.

Comment: @ahmed7am1d did you prepend 'Bearer' to you're token before saving it to local storage?

Answer (score 0):

Try post request and also get the token from local storage outside of request definition. I think one of theese will fix your problem.

Comment: I will try and let you know, thanks.